# What event listener to use when listening to a call of QR API?

Tags: javascript, html, css, qr-code

I am using https://goqr.me/api/ to replace an existing image with the resulting QR but it has  a delay that depends on the input.  I want to listen to an event the moment the QR has changed.

What event listener should I use?

```js
const image = document.getElementById("myImg");
const button = document.getElementById("myButton");



function changeImage() {
image.setAttribute("src","http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=www.facebook.com&size=150x150&margin=15");
}

button.addEventListener("click", changeImage)
```

```html
<img id="myImg" src ="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d0/QR_code_for_mobile_English_Wikipedia.svg/1200px-QR_code_for_mobile_English_Wikipedia.svg.png" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;">
<button id="myButton">Change!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const image = document.getElementById("myImg");
const button = document.getElementById("myButton");

function changeImage() {
  image.src = `http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=150x150&margin=15&data=${Math.round(Math.random() * 100)}`
}

//  use load event to listen to src change.
image.addEventListener("load", () => {
  console.log("load");
})

button.addEventListener("click", changeImage)
```

```html
<img id="myImg" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d0/QR_code_for_mobile_English_Wikipedia.svg/1200px-QR_code_for_mobile_English_Wikipedia.svg.png" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;">
<button id="myButton">Change!</button>
```